# bit-wise operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only

Tags: firefox, glsl, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to make a function that get a bit position for a color in GLSL.

```
 precision highp float;
 uniform sampler2D uTexture0;
 varying vec2 vTextureCoords;

int getBit(float color, int bit){
        highp int colorInt = int(color);
        return (colorInt >> bit) & 1;
}

void main(void) {
   highp vec4 texelColour = texture2D(uTexture0, vec2(vTextureCoords.s, vTextureCoords.t));

 if(getBit(texelColour.r * 255.0, 7) == 1 ){
       gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8);
 }else{
       gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
 }
```

}

chrome and firefox return this error

```
ERROR: 0:35: '>>' : bit-wise operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only  
ERROR: 0:35: '&' : bit-wise operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
```

I'm trying to force the version in the first line of my shader, like this :

```
#version 130
```

but the console return that the version is not supported.

Is there a way to create subroutines for the getBit function ?
Or what settings to enable for implements bitwize operator in sharder fragment ?

thanks for reply.

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding a solution in writing my own and shift function

```
 int getBit(float num, float b){
        num = num * 255.0;
        int bit = 0;
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
            if(num >=  pow(2.0,float(i))){
                num = num - pow(2.0,float(i));
                if(b == float(i)){
                    bit = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return bit;
    }


 if(getBit(texelColour.r , 3.0) != 0 && getBit(texelColour.g * 255.0, 0.0) == 0 &&  getBit(texelColour.b * 255.0, 0.0) == 0){
   gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8);
}else{
   gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

I'm newb in glsl so it can surely be better but it works.

Ps: my need is only for 1 byte decimal

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare you are using es3 in the top of the shader:

`#version 300 es`

That would also require that you change the syntax of the rest of the shader (no more `varying` but rather `in` and `out`, etc.).